# nodejs disable unicode encoding of string

Tags: javascript, node.js, unicode, character-encoding

I have created a endpoint using `express` that accepts `POST` request from other system. This request contains sha1 hash that validates request.
Example request generated by `ncat`:

```
POST /webhook HTTP/1.1
Host: **nothing_to_see_here**
User-Agent: **nothing_to_see_here**
Content-Length: **nothing_to_see_here**
Accept: text/plain
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
X-Forwarded-For: **nothing_to_see_here**
X-Forwarded-Proto: **nothing_to_see_here**
X-Shop-Domain: **nothing_to_see_here**
X-Shop-License: **nothing_to_see_here**
X-Shop-Version: **nothing_to_see_here**
X-Webhook-Id: **nothing_to_see_here**
X-Webhook-Name: **nothing_to_see_here**
X-Webhook-Sha1: bbebc1d43ee4eeeed251a1a899e1f2b92eab0008

{"user_id":"1","login":"","date_add":"2022-03-24 18:46:00","lastvisit":"2022-03-24 18:46:01","verify_email":"0","origin":"0","registered":"1","firstname":"\u017baneta","lastname":"\u017b\u00f3\u0142\u0107","email":"ciekals11@gmail.com","discount":"0.00","newsletter":0,"active":"1","lang_id":"1","comment":"asdads\r\nzxczxc\r\nqweqweq","groups":[{"group_id":"1","name":"hurtowa 1","discount":"0.00","price_level":"2"}],"addresses":[],"additional_fields":[{"field_id":"1","type":"2","locate":"7","req":"1","active":"1","order":"14","value":"1"},{"field_id":"17","type":"1","locate":"1","req":"0","active":"1","order":"2","value":""}]}
```

In this example in body under `firstname` key there is `"\u017baneta"` which is encoded string that translates to `"Żaneta"`

My problem is that hash given to me in `X-Webhook-Sha1` header was generated with PHP that treat `\u017b` as 6 char string.

My endpoint is created with node and here `\u017b` is treated as 1 char (`Ż`) and my sha1 hash is different than what have server sent.

How can I prevent this?

What I have tryed:

- `utf8.encode` and `utf8.decode`
- passing `Buffer.from(reqBody, 'utf-8')` to shaSum.update
- changing `crypto` to `sha1`
- using shell commands
- `String.raw`
- `JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(reqBody))`

Only thing that works is when I explicity replace every `\u` with `\\u` but methods like `.replace()` and `.replaceAll()` does not work on this string in node. (Or it does but I'm unable to make it work).

Examples of generating sha1 hash
(Sum is generated as `sha1(sth1:sth2:reqBody})`

PHP

```
echo sha1('1:test:{"user_id":"1","login":"","date_add":"2022-03-24 18:46:00","lastvisit":"2022-03-24 18:46:01","verify_email":"0","origin":"0","registered":"1","firstname":"\u017baneta","lastname":"\u017b\u00f3\u0142\u0107","email":"test@gmail.com","discount":"0.00","newsletter":0,"active":"1","lang_id":"1","comment":"asdads\r\nzxczxc\r\nqweqweq","groups":[{"group_id":"1","name":"hurtowa 1","discount":"0.00","price_level":"2"}],"addresses":[],"additional_fields":[{"field_id":"1","type":"2","locate":"7","req":"1","active":"1","order":"14","value":"1"},{"field_id":"17","type":"1","locate":"1","req":"0","active":"1","order":"2","value":""}]}');
// output: bbebc1d43ee4eeeed251a1a899e1f2b92eab0008
```

NodeJS

```js
const crypto = require('crypto');

const shaSum = crypto.createHash('sha1');
shaSum.update('1:test:{"user_id":"1","login":"","date_add":"2022-03-24 18:46:00","lastvisit":"2022-03-24 18:46:01","verify_email":"0","origin":"0","registered":"1","firstname":"\u017baneta","lastname":"\u017b\u00f3\u0142\u0107","email":"test@gmail.com","discount":"0.00","newsletter":0,"active":"1","lang_id":"1","comment":"asdads\\r\\nzxczxc\\r\\nqweqweq","groups":[{"group_id":"1","name":"hurtowa 1","discount":"0.00","price_level":"2"}],"addresses":[],"additional_fields":[{"field_id":"1","type":"2","locate":"7","req":"1","active":"1","order":"14","value":"1"},{"field_id":"17","type":"1","locate":"1","req":"0","active":"1","order":"2","value":""}]}');
const hash = shaSum.digest('hex');

console.log(hash);
// output: 36fad2735dcbf8b1b63517cd6cff1958dae93b94
```

Comment: I'm not sure i understand, do you want to escape the backslash, e.g. `'{"firstname":"\\u017baneta","lastname":"\\u017b\\u00f3\\u0142\\u0107"}'`?

Comment: I will update my question to clarify.

Comment: If you get the string as a string, it should be in the proper form. The `\uxxxx` notation is an escape for string literals in code, there is no effect on strings e.g. received from backend. If you want to have a string that has those symbols (backslash, u, four digits), from a literal, you can for example escape the backslash: `'\\u1234'`, or use `String.raw\`\u1234\``.

Comment: "you can for example escape the backslash: `'\\u1234'`, or use `String.raw\`\u1234\``" I would love to but how can I escape them? `String.raw` does not change a thing

Comment: `const data1 = String.raw\`{"firstname":"\u017baneta","lastname":"\u017b\u00f3\u0142\u0107"}\`; const data2 = '{"firstname":"Żaneta","lastname":"Żółć"}'; console.log(data1.length !== data2.length, data1, data2);`, maybe i am still misunderstanding what you intend to do.

Comment: when I perform `console.log(String.raw`${data}`.length);
console.log(data2.length);` both console.logs show same value and they should not. `\u017b` should be seen as 6 chars and not 1

Comment: I have no idea what `data` is, but my glass ball is telling me it's from your server, and it sends you a string that doesn't contain any sequences of 'backslash, u, digit, digit, digit, digit', but the unicode characters.

Comment: @ASDFGerte I have updated my question to clarify some more so you don't have to use your glass ball. Sorry for that.